# What did Joanna do to prompt her pregnancy?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

In *Mr Robot* season 1, when the detectives come to Tyrell's house to question him, Joanna starts labor. A fork (or other kitchen implement) is seen with the tip covered in blood. How exactly does this relate to Joanna's oh-so-fortunate labor timing?

Answer (score 7):

This is explained at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mr._Robot_episodes#Season_1_.282015.29)

> When police question the Wellicks about Sharon's murder, Joanna secretly **breaks her own water with a fork** to distract them.

I won't get into the gory gynocological details but it's definitely *hardcore*. This is a procedure usually carried out by a medical professional or doctor.

> If your water is being broken under the management of your doctor, it is generally a safe procedure. But you should never try to break your water at home without supervision. Your labor could start very quickly after your water is broken, or the baby may be in a dangerous position that could cause a complication.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.healthline.com/health/pregnancy/how-to-get-your-water-to-break#intro1)</sup>

Try googling for "Breaking your own water" and you will see for yourself.